# Gradient of $∇x: A^2x$

Tags: calculus

Let $x ∈ \mathbb R^n$ and $A ∈ \mathbb R^{n×n}$
What is the gradient $∇x:A^2x$?

I see a rules that often used when differentiating multivariate functions:
For all  $A∈\mathbb R^{m×n}$ ,  $∇x:Ax=A^⊤$,

So I process the $x: A^2x$ to $∇x: A(Ax)$ and use previous rules
It becomes  $A  A^⊤$

Is it correct?
If not, what should I do with it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should use Latex to edit your question in this site. This is definitely needed for your question as there’re too many ambiguities without Latex.

Comment: Do you want the gradient $\nabla x:A^2x$, or the gradient *of* $\nabla x:A^2x$? Part of me suspects you want $\nabla_xA^2x$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, ∇xA2x .

Comment: Please use MathJax in comments too.

Comment: Sorry, it is my first time to use this site. I'm not very familiar with some specific operations

Comment: See  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ,

Comment: When you write "What is the gradient of $\Psi$?" then $\Psi$ should be a scalar function of an obvious vector variable, say $x$. But $\Psi:=\ \nabla x : A^2 x$ is no such function. In fact this $\Psi$ makes no sense at all.

Comment: I only suggested MathJax in comments because when I asked which of multiple possibilities is applicable, your reply left me none the wiser. Was my first idea right, the second, the third?

Comment: With $M:N$ you mean $M:N=\text{tr}(M^TN)$?

Comment: @J.G. You said, "Part of me suspects you want ∇xA2x." That is what I want.

Comment: Ah, the third. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\nabla_xAx=A^T$, $\nabla_xA^2x=(A^2)^T=(A^T)^2$.

Comment: Can you give a brief explanation about why ∇x A2x= (A2)T?

Comment: I previously thought it would be A*AT

Comment: @YahuWang I'm just replacing $A$ with $A^2$ in the identity. Maybe using different letters would help: take $B=A^2$ in $\nabla_xBx=B^T$.

Comment: Oh, that looks to make more sense, thank you!